# Return attribute even when the object is None type

Tags: python-3.x

This example might not be very good but the original code is way more confusing so I try a simplify version
so I have two class

```
class Sample():
    def __init__(self, sample, antibody = None):
        self.sample = sample
        self.antibody = None
    def pass_in_sample(self, antibody):
        if antibody:
           self.antibody= antibody

class Antibody():
    def__init__(self, sequence):
        self.Antibody_sequence= sequence

antibody= Antibody(sequence)
sample_object = A(sample, antibody = antibody)
```

Now I am parsing a large csv file and some sample exist but there is no antibody

and I am trying to do the following

```
def main()
   for sample in sample_list:
      sample_object = Sample(sample)
      print(sample_object.Antibody.Antibody_sequence)
```

but if it antibody is None to begin with, so even if sample_object 
 was able to create, sample_object.Antibody will return None, so sample_object.Antibody.Antibody_sequence cannot return a name attribute because None type does not have attribute of Antibody_sequence

I know I can filter out None in the main method, but is there anyway to define in the class that if sample_object.Antibodyis None, then their return attribute will also be None, and not give an error

Thank you

Comment: "is there anyway to define in the class that if sample_object is None, then their return attribute will also be None" - yes, literally: `if sample_object is None: return None`.

Comment: where are you defining that? I want to define in class A but there is no name attribute in class A, they are in class B.

Comment: In your class B, `name` is never defined in `__init__`. It can return a `name` attribute of None.

Comment: I fixed my example shown above, instead of A and B now I have sample and antibody. I want sample_object.Antibody = None but when I am calling sample_object.Antibody.Antibody_sequence it wouldn't error out but instead just say None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Sample` has an attribute `antibody` not `Antibody`, so I am going to assume that `sample_object.Antibody.Antibody_sequence` was a typo and that you meant `sample_object.antibody.Antibody_sequence` as I try to answer your question.

To state specifically (as you did in the comment), when you have the situation where you have:

```
sample_object.antibody == None
```

You want:

```
sample_object.antibody.Antibody_sequence
```

not to cause an error (throw an exception) but instead result in a `None`.

This is not possible. Let me illustrate why. The line `sample_object.antibody.Antibody_sequence` can be written equivalently as:

```
((sample_object).antibody).Antibody_sequence
```

So `(sample_object)` is a reference to an instance of the class Sample. You then reference into that class and see if it has the attribute `antibody`. If it does it return the value of the attribute. So if that attribute value is None, then what you have is this:

```
(None).Antibody_sequence
```

Of course None does not have any attributes, so this fails. The important point here is that no mater what you do inside `Sample`, you cannot affect what is the None you returned does after it has been returned. So, no there is no way to satisfy your request that 'sample_object.Antibody = None but when I am calling sample_object.Antibody.Antibody_sequence it wouldn't error out but instead just say None'

However, that does not mean that you cannot achieve what you want to do. You just need to use something instead of None as the null antibody initialiser. This below should achieve what you are trying to do.

You can create a class specifically to use instead of the None initialiser for antibody in your Sample class.

```
class AntibodyNone():
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

    @property
    def Antibody_sequence(self):
        return None

a_none = AntibodyNone()

class Sample():
    def __init__(self, sample, antibody = None):
        self.sample = sample
        if antibody:
            self.antibody = antibody
        else:
            self.antibody = a_none

    def pass_in_sample(self, antibody):
        if antibody:
           self.antibody = antibody
        else:
            self.antibody = a_none


s = Sample("sample_val")

s.antibody.Antibody_sequence
```

In this example `s.antibody` is uninitialised, but you can still reference `s.antibody.Antibody_sequence` through it and get None instead of an error.

You can't test`sample_object.antibody == None`. The `__bool__()` gives the class 'Falsiness'. So if you test `if s.antibody` it will be False. That is how you add 'Truthiness' to a class in python 3, if you want to do it for python 2, you need to add `__nonzero__()`.